# How can I access multiple Raspberry-based machines remotely (IoT)

Tags: rest, raspberry-pi, cloud, iot, remote-access

We have developed a machine which is based on a central brain, a Raspberry Pi computer. It uses a 4G/5G Router to get access to the outter world. I am expecting to have hundreds of machines like that. Now, I have created a REST based API so I can access a database within the Raspberry's memory/disk and here comes my question: Considering that static IPs are not free, and not precisely cheap, what's the way to go? One new domain for each machine so that domain will be the endpoint of the API? The problem I see here is that I would have to register and maintain hundreds of domains (e.g. [www.machine1.com](http://www.machine1.com), [www.machine2.com](http://www.machine2.com), etc...). I don't think this is the right way to make it, correct? When I think of a cloud-based or on-site server solution, I still have the problem that the cloud app or server needs to know where to find each machine for API communication (static IP or domain).

I would appreciate if someone could help me taking a decission on how to pick the right solution. Thank you!

So far, I am considering either buying static IP for each machine or a specific/ad-hoc domain for each machine. None of the solutions seem to be an efficient or sensible approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,are you sure you have a public IP on the remote machines?
Are the port remotely accessibles?
In certain cases ISP use a private network for 4G/5G so they don't have to possess as many public IPv4 as devices... It's the case in France for example.

Let's put aside the REST API for now.

You then have the following 2 cases:

### Case A: Public IP

If you have a public IP with accessible ports, you can use a central server on which every machine will periodically connect on to provide/update their IP.

Then the central server logs these "assets" and their IP.
If you don't want to write and manage this server, you can use a DynamicDns service of your choice.

### Case B: Private IP

If your machines are on a NAT network, you have then to use a central server on which every machine will connect and then wait for commands from this connection.

Security concerns put aside, the easiest way to do so is with ssh as you can bind a local port to a remote connection (see `man ssh`, options: -L or -D).
On a security perspective, you'll have to at least chroot/jail every incoming connection to the central server to ensure noone can interfer on this server.

**In both case, be sure to secure the way your clients are connecting and talking to the central server.**

### Now that you know how to connect, how to talk with your API?

Case A is straightforward: use your API normally as you have the remote IP/dns.

Case B as you won't have the possibility to open ports, you'll have to talk through the tunnel between the machine and the central server.